# PDO Prepare Query - SQL Error Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm having trouble running this query

```
    //Insert power stats
try {   
    $STH = $db -> prepare(
            "INSERT INTO statsRounds
            (
                version,
                timeFormat,
                mapNumber,
                mapName,
                duration,
                startTic,
                endTic,
                avgEfficiencyPts,
                redPowerPercent,
                bluePowerPercent
            ) 
            VALUES
            (
                $wdlround->versionNumber,
                $wdlround->timeFormat,
                $wdlround->mapNumber,
                $wdlround->mapName,
                $wdlround->durationTics,
                $wdlround->startTic,
                $wdlround->endTic,
                $wdlround->averageEfficiencyPoints,
                $wdlround->redPowerPercent,
                $wdlround->bluePowerPercent
            )"
        );


    //Execute query
    $STH -> execute();      

} //try

catch(PDOException $ex) {
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
```

Upon execution I receive an error

```
Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.22.20.55.00, 6, Lazarus Revisited - SMARTCTF01, 18193, 0, ' at line 17
```

I've checked to make sure the values exist in $wdlround->versionNumber to $wdlround->bluePowerPercent and they do.  The connection to the db is fine as well.  I've posted the db table as well, see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xarlm.jpg

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here!

EDIT:

Adding

```
// ECHO QUERY
$mystr = "INSERT INTO statsRounds( 'version', 'time', 'mapNumber', 'mapName', 'duration', 'startTic', 'endTic', 'avgEfficiencyPts', 'redPowerPercent', 'bluePowerPercent') VALUES ( " . $wdlround->versionNumber . ", " . $wdlround->timeFormat . ", " . $wdlround->mapNumber . ", " . $wdlround->mapName . ", " . $wdlround->durationTics . ", " . $wdlround->startTic . ", " . $wdlround->endTic . ", " . $wdlround->averageEfficiencyPoints . ", " . $wdlround->redPowerPercent . ", " . $wdlround->bluePowerPercent . ") ";
echo "MYSTR = $mystr<br>";
```

Results in

```
MYSTR = INSERT INTO statsRounds( 'version', 'time', 'mapNumber', 'mapName', 'duration', 'startTic', 'endTic', 'avgEfficiencyPts', 'redPowerPercent', 'bluePowerPercent') VALUES ( 4, 2014.07.22.21.03.11, 6, Lazarus Revisited - SMARTCTF01, 16418, 0, 130136, 107.83333333333, 108.33333333333, 93.333333333333)
```

Being output

Comment: Echo the query and see how the query is formed.

Comment: INSERT INTO statsRounds(
version,
timeFormat,
mapNumber,
mapName,
duration,
startTic,
endTic,
avgEfficiencyPts,
redPowerPercent,
bluePowerPercent
)
VALUES (
NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL
)

Through the SQL command line inserts fine.

What do you mean by echo the query?

Comment: If I echo the query this is the result:

MYSTR = INSERT INTO statsRounds( 'version', 'time', 'mapNumber', 'mapName', 'durstion', 'startTic', 'endTic', 'avgEfficiencyPts', 'redPowerPercent', 'bluePowerPercent) VALUES ( 4, 2014.07.22.20.55.00, 6, Lazarus Revisited - SMARTCTF01, 18193, 0, 112948, 103.66666666667, 150, 80)

Comment: `( 'version', 'time', 'mapNumber', 'mapName', 'durstion', 'startTic', 'endTic', 'avgEfficiencyPts', 'redPowerPercent', 'bluePowerPercent)` quote missing for `'bluePowerPercent` plus, those shouldn't be quotes but no quotes or backticks `\`` (those are columns, not strings) - where are the quotes coming from, or  is that what you want entered in DB?

Comment: 1. missing a quote for last column `'bluePowerPercent`. 2. assuming that those quote's are not really there, if there then remove them or replace them with backtique.

Comment: This was just a test string to echo the query so I could see what was going on, it doesn't affect the actual query (I wish it was that easy :( )

Comment: Any which way, you have one missing for `'bluePowerPercent` as per your echo'd comment (or is that a typo?). You'd need to show us the rest of the code that is generating this.

Comment: I've updated the main post to show!

Comment: Again, you're using quotes for your columns `INSERT INTO statsRounds( 'version', 'time', 'mapNumber', 'mapName', 'duration', 'startTic', 'endTic', 'avgEfficiencyPts', 'redPowerPercent', 'bluePowerPercent')` either remove them or wrap them in backticks `\``; **there** is your error.

Comment: doesn't work since it's just an echo (which is set before the query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your post your `INSERT` query looks like

```
INSERT INTO statsRounds(version, 
time, 
......
) 
VALUES (
 4, 
2014.07.22.20.55.00, <-- Here surround the value with '' 
6, 
......
)
```

Problem is `time` is a `VARCHAR` column (per the posted link for DB schema) and the value for it have no quotes. you should pass the value for it like `'2014.07.22.20.55.00'`. Likewise for all `VARCHAR`/`CHAR` column surround the value with quote.

Your `INSERT` statement should look like

```
INSERT INTO statsRounds(
version, 
time, 
mapNumber, 
mapName, 
durstion, 
startTic, 
endTic, 
avgEfficiencyPts, 
redPowerPercent, 
bluePowerPercent) 
VALUES (
'4', 
'2014.07.22.20.55.00', 
6, 
'Lazarus Revisited - SMARTCTF01', 
18193, 
0, 
112948, 
103.66666666667, 
150, 
80)
```

Comment: so something like 
VALUES( $wdlround->versionNumber, '$wdlround->timeFormat', $wdlround->mapNumber, '$wdlround->mapName', $wdlround->durationTics,     $wdlround->startTic, $wdlround->endTic, $wdlround->averageEfficiencyPoints, $wdlround->redPowerPercent, $wdlround->bluePowerPercent )"

?

Comment: Yep kind of but don't ask me; have no idea about PHP but that's surely is the problem/issue with your query. Surround the values with quote and all will be fine.

Comment: It was the problem!  I had no idea I had to encapsulate varchars.  Great thing to know.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not preparing the right way, here is how you should do it:

```
$STH = $db -> prepare(
        "INSERT INTO statsRounds
        (
            version,
            timeFormat,
            mapNumber,
            mapName,
            duration,
            startTic,
            endTic,
            avgEfficiencyPts,
            redPowerPercent,
            bluePowerPercent
        ) 
        VALUES
        (
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?
        )"
    );


//Execute query
$STH -> execute(array(
            $wdlround->versionNumber,
            $wdlround->timeFormat,
            $wdlround->mapNumber,
            $wdlround->mapName,
            $wdlround->durationTics,
            $wdlround->startTic,
            $wdlround->endTic,
            $wdlround->averageEfficiencyPoints,
            $wdlround->redPowerPercent,
            $wdlround->bluePowerPercent
        ));
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this as well but it results in the same error:

    Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.22.21.03.11, 6, Lazarus Revisited - SMARTCTF01, 16418, 0, ' at line 17

Comment: Not sure if it is just good practice or not, but the statement executes fine without the array() stuff.

Comment: No its not good practice because it expose you to sql injection and also error prone just like this quoting issue you just encountered.

Comment: Welcome so when you get a chance fix this !